# My question is about Cron error in magento 2.3

Tags: php, magento, cron, indexer

Have same issue with cron indexer again. Same thing as before month ago on magento 2.

Showing after running php cron:run or php index:reindex same error like before month ago. Last time I installed missing php extensions and give permission to necessary folders on Ubuntu. How have same problem with same output error.

Last time dom, xml extension were problem and permissions on folders. After doing this cron job run like a charm and one more time after that.

On command `php bin/magento cron:run` get this output:

> In abstract.php line 144
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>
> In abstract.php line 128
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Running php7 on ubuntu virtualbox as said this was error before solved with above mentioned how have same problem and its not the same thing. PHPMYADMIN works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the hostname under `app/etc/env.php`

> Change "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"